# BlackBerry Widget application - GPS location is always 0,0

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-widgets

I am trying to get the GPS location in a widget application on a blackberry, but the API always returns a latitude and longitude of 0,0.

Simulator: storm 2 (9550)/ bold(9700) and OS: 5.0/5.0

IDE:Eclipse

the html page code as below:

```
var modeCellsite   = 0;
var modeAssisted   = 1;
var modeAutonomous = 2;

function locationChanged()
{

    alert("Lat " + blackberry.location.latitude +
          " Lon " + blackberry.location.longitude +
          " Time " + blackberry.location.timestamp );
    return true;
}

if ( window.blackberry && blackberry.location.GPSSupported )
{
    var isUpdated = false;
    var theCount = 0;
    alert("Location tracking is supported");
    blackberry.location.onLocationUpdate("locationChanged()");
    blackberry.location.setAidMode(modeAutonomous);
    while ( theCount++ < 10 && !isUpdated )
        isUpdated = blackberry.location.refreshLocation();
}
else
{
    document.write("Location tracking is not supported");
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem, with slightly different but spritually simial js.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you turned ON GPS in the SIM before running your widget.

> ```
> For Example in the simulator goto:
>     Simulate -> GPS Location...
>     Under Route Click "add"
>     Choice Random Route Generator
>        Number of Legs 1000
>        Travel Time 600
>        click OK
>     Click Play arrow
> ```

Comment: This doesn't change anything for me... I think that setting a location should work as well as sending it on a huge path.

Comment: @Nilloc I was just pointing out that you should make sure to turn on the sim's GPS otherwise you will get 0,0 (the default location).  The reason for using a "huge path" is your users are never going to be standing still so you should be testing a path not a single location.  I will say that in Java it takes several seconds to get an updated location, so I don't think calling refreshlocation() in a tight loop is going to do much.  I believe the examples I have seen show it being called once and then again inside of the locationChanged() handler.