# Get GPS location on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

I can't read location with this function.  When I try to get location information, it always returns altitude 0, longitude 0.

```
    void getirGps(){
        Criteria myCriteria = new Criteria();
        myCriteria.setCostAllowed(false);

        try
        {
            LocationProvider myLocationProvider =
                LocationProvider.getInstance(myCriteria);

            try
            {
                Location myLocation = myLocationProvider.getLocation(300);

                seTLatitude(myLocation.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLatitude());// sunlarıda bir public statıc dene..
                seTLongitude(myLocation.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLongitude());
                Dialog.alert("latitude = "+GPSThread.latitude +" longi"+GPSThread.longitude);
                velocity   = myLocation.getSpeed();
                heading    = myLocation.getCourse();
                timeStamp  = myLocation.getTimestamp();
                nmeaString = myLocation.getExtraInfo
                    ("application/X-jsr179-location-nmea");
            }
            catch ( InterruptedException iex )
            {
                Dialog.alert("InterruptedException");
                return;
            }
            catch ( LocationException lex )
            {
                Dialog.alert("LocationException lex");
                return;
            }
        }
        catch ( LocationException lex )
        {
            Dialog.alert("LocationException lex2");
            return;
        }

    }


public void doThis(){

    MapView mapView = new MapView();
    mapView.setLatitude( (int) Threads.latitude);//39.9208, Longitude = 32.8541 
    mapView.setLongitude((int) Threads.longitude);
    mapView.setZoom(10);
    MapsArguments mapsArgs = new MapsArguments(mapView);
    Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MAPS, mapsArgs);

    Dialog.alert("latitude = "+Threads.latitude +" longi"+Threads.longitude);
```

Comment: and when i try my app in simulator, i change location information on menu, gps locaiton tag..

Comment: I assume you are concerned that Dialog poped up in doThis() is showing zero values.   But you haven't included enough code to figure out how the values get from the LocationProvider to the doThis() method.  I suggest you break down your problem further - add some printouts near the LocationProvider, to see what value it returns, right when it gets returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the [GPS functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989166/blackberry-widget-application-gps-location-is-always-0-0) is enabled on the device.

Comment: i did all necessary test for it. everything right, except request answer.